# How to get all data in Expression Builder Access 2010?

Tags: forms, ms-access, vba, report, ms-access-2010

I have a combobox and it has 3 options "All", "A" and "E"

If I choose "A" all letter "A" will appear in my report if "E" all letter "E" and if I choose "ALL" both letter will appear in my report how will I do that in Expression Builder here is my sample code I don't know what to put in All

```
=IIF([Forms]![AuditTrail]![actionCombo] = "A", "A" , IIF([Forms]![AuditTrail]![actionCombo] = "E", "E", "")
```

What should I put after the condition in letter "E"

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

```
=IIF([Forms]![AuditTrail]![actionCombo] = "A" Or [Forms]![AuditTrail]![actionCombo] = "E", [Forms]![AuditTrail]![actionCombo], [NameOfTheFieldYourFilterOn])
```

Comment: what do you mean by Name Of The Field Your Filter On? sorry I'm not good at english, actionCombo?

Comment: I get it now Thank you so much